# Debugging trivial functions in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

Recently I just started working on iOS game programming, and I find several things confusing. (FYI, I am working on a simple game with code provided on makegamewith.us)

First, I just found out that only the main function is executed. By this I mean we use the main function to activate iOS simulator, so that we will be able to load our game. Then I realize that breakpoints only work in main functions. As I put breakpoints in other files (such as creature.m, a game component), despite that I use a function to create creature objects in the game, Xcode won't stop at that function. The iOS simulator will be called, and then the game will be automatically loaded.

So here is the question: how can I debug then?

I assume that function is called when I run the game, but Xcode just ignores any other function in other files except the main function in main.m.

Also, I encountered several "Couldn't find member variable" situations. I wonder how to prevent this from happening. The whole sprite builder publishing to Xcode thing appears blurry. I would appreciate if someone can explain how the whole thing works.

Update:

I realize that I didn't explicitly call any of the functions I have in other files (for instance, Grid.m as shown below). By main function, I mean the int main function in main.m. So the problem might possibly be that I didn't explicitly call that function in main? (but I think what main.m is responsible for is launching the program.)

In main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

@autoreleasepool //if I put a breakpoint here this will definitely work
{
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
    return retVal;
    }
}
```

Grid.m

```
#import "Grid.h"
#import "Creature.h"

// these are variables that cannot be changed
static const int GRID_ROWS = 8;
static const int GRID_COLUMNS = 10;

@implementation Grid {
    NSMutableArray *_gridArray;
    float _cellWidth;
    float _cellHeight;
}

- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    [self setupGrid];

    // accept touches on the grid
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)setupGrid //****if I put breakpoint here, it doesn't work****
{
    // divide the grid's size by the number of columns/rows to figure out the right width and height of each cell
    _cellWidth = self.contentSize.width / GRID_COLUMNS;
    _cellHeight = self.contentSize.height / GRID_ROWS;

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;

    // initialize the array as a blank NSMutableArray
    _gridArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    // initialize Creatures
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_ROWS; i++) {
        // this is how you create two dimensional arrays in Objective-C. You put arrays into arrays.
    _gridArray[i] = [NSMutableArray array];
    x = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < GRID_COLUMNS; j++) {
        Creature *creature = [[Creature alloc] initCreature];
            creature.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
            creature.position = ccp(x, y);
            [self addChild:creature];

            // this is shorthand to access an array inside an array
            _gridArray[i][j] = creature;

            // make creatures visible to test this method, remove this once we know we have filled the grid properly
            creature.isAlive = YES;

            x+=_cellWidth;
        }

        y += _cellHeight;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: The breakpoints will *fire* for any code, anywhere, that is executed, so I suspect you are not calling these functions correctly.  Please post some example code.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean. "Only the main function is executed" what does this mean? If it means that only the main function in the main.m file is run then that's just not true. "Breakpoints only run in main functions" what is a "main function"? You can have a function in any file (creature.m for instance) and a breakpoint will break when that line of code is executed. Also, you shouldn't edit anything in the main.m file. Just pretend it isn't there. It is only there to launch the app. You need to include some code here. Also, I think you need to start from the basics.

Comment: If you're saying that you're actually leveraging the `main()` function to do pretty much anything, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I dont wanna sound harsh but I stopped reading at the first paragraph. friendly advice: read a book or two to learn the terminology

Comment: @Fogmeister By main function I mean the function int main in main.m. I have some previous experience in C++, so I assume everything in Objective-C works similar to the way in C++. This might be wrong, but I think Objective oriented languages do share a lot in common.

Comment: Show the code that calls that function. I.e. the code that creates that "node" (I assume we are talking cocos2d here? - if so tag your question with cocos2d).

Comment: @TheCoolestPenguin you are correct that the "first" function run is main() in main.m. But it launches the Objective-C project and you should never (rarely) need to edit anything in main(). Object Oriented languages do have some shared concepts but there is no way that Perl, Java and Objective-C are related. Approach the problem as an Objective-C problem instead of a C++ problem. You are, after all, programming in Objective-C.

Comment: @TheCoolestPenguin where is the method `- (void)onEnter` called from?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks anyways. I am just trying to walk through tutorials provided on makegamewithus.com (and I think they do omit a lot important stuff). I just want to learn the whole structure thing, like how sprite builder works with Coco2D and stuff. I have experience in C and C++... it is just the debugging thing in an iOS project appears confusing.

Comment: @Fogmeister I think it is a function comes with Cocos2D

Comment: Show the code that adds the node, or is that within SpriteBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your `main()` function -- almost the only thing it does is to call `UIApplicationMain()`. This is true for any iOS application. So the real work is being done by `UIApplicationMain()`, and we should find out about that. Here's [the description from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain):

> This function instantiates the application object from the principal
>   class and instantiates the delegate (if any) from the given class and
>   sets the delegate for the application. It also sets up the main event
>   loop, including the application’s run loop, and begins processing
>   events. If the application’s Info.plist file specifies a main nib file
>   to be loaded, by including the NSMainNibFile key and a valid nib file
>   name for the value, this function loads that nib file.

So if there's a problem with your app, it's likely related to the application delegate, your `AppController` class. Set a breakpoint in your `-[AppController application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method -- that's what the application itself will call on its delegate when the app is ready to run. Your `UIApplicationMain()` call in `main()` looks OK, so the debugger should hit a breakpoint in your `...didFinishLaunching...` method. Step through that method and make sure that you're setting up a window, setting a root view controller, etc. If you're not sure what needs to happen, try creating a new single-view project and looking at the code that's provided there.

Comment: I think this question will evolve into "why isn't my `[CCNode onEnter]` method being called?"

Comment: @trojanfoe I expect you're right. But OP might learn to help himself by stepping through each level, checking the docs, and ensuring that the right thing is happening. (We can dream, right?) At the moment, OP seems to think that the debugger won't break in any functions other than `main()`, and doing what I've described above will show that that's not true.